# TightVNC on Windows Server 2008 disconnects client after login

Tags: windows-server-2008, vnc

I have TightVNC server on Windows Server 2008 and it breaks the connection right after the login. The same happens both on linux and windows clients:

```
Connected to RFB server, using protocol version 3.8
Enabling TightVNC protocol extensions
Performing standard VNC authentication
Password: 
Authentication successful
vncviewer: VNC server closed connection
```

Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: I have this exact thing happen with TightVNC on the client and UltraVNC on the server. I haven't take the time to trouble-shoot yet. What's the VNC server being used?

Comment: it's tightvnc server, not ultravnc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is the manifestation of same problem described here:

[Workaround to Run VNC Server in Windows Vista](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2006/12/13/workaround-to-run-vnc-server-in-windows-vista/)

> The problems are caused by Windows
>   Vista new security feature called
>   Session 0 Isolation. Previous versions
>   of Windows ran system services in the
>   same login session as the locally
>   logged-in user (Session 0). In Windows
>   Vista, Session 0 is now reserved for
>   these services, and all interactive
>   logins are done in other sessions,
>   causing VNC server unable to accept
>   incoming remote control connection
>   request.

and the proposed solution:

> So in order to make VNC server on
>   Windows Vista works properly, the
>   workaround resolution (at least until
>   the VNC developers to come out with
>   proper fix or update to address the
>   new security constraint in Windows
>   Vista) is to run VNC server in user
>   mode.

Or try if it works with [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/).

P.S: Here is the MSDN article about [Application Compatibility: Session 0 Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756986.aspx).

Comment: are there security risks when running vnc in usermode, or is it more secure by not being at session 0?  my gut says more secure, but not sure myself